# How to build a numpy matrix one row at a time?

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to build a matrix one row at a time.

```
import numpy as np

f = np.matrix([])
f = np.vstack([ f, np.matrix([1]) ])
```

This is the error message.

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 0 and the array at index 1 has size 1

As you can see, np.matrix([]) is NOT an empty list.  I'm going to have to do this some other way.  But what?  I'd rather not do an ugly workaround kludge.

Comment: could you give a sample of what `P` contains? and what b is?  Likely P[i,j] doesn't have the same dimensions as b

Comment: I've simplified the example to get rid of all that extraneous stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass some dimension to the initial matrix. Either fill it with some zeros or use `np.empty()`:

```
f = np.empty(shape = [1,1])
f = np.vstack([f,np.matrix([1])])
```

Comment: BTW, matrix is deprecated. use `np.array`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.hstack` instead for the first case, then use `vstack` iteratively.

```py
arr = np.array([])
arr = np.hstack((arr, np.array([1,1,1])))

arr = np.vstack((arr, np.array([2,2,2])))
```

Now you can convert into a matrix.

```
mat = np.asmatrix(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good grief.  It appears there is no way to do what I want. Kludgetown it is.  I'll build an array with a bogus first entry, then when I'm done make a copy without the bogosity.